# Subtracting group-wise mean from a matrix or data frame in python (the "within" transformation for panel data)

Tags: python, r, pandas, statistics, economics

In datasets where units are observed multiple times, many statistical methods (particularly in econometrics) apply a transformation to the data in which the group-wise mean of each variable is subtracted off, creating a dataset of unit-level (non-standardized) anomalies from a unit level mean.

I want to do this in Python.

In R, it is handled quite cleanly by the `demeanlist` function in the `lfe` package.  Here's an example dataset, which a grouping variable `fac`:

```
> df <- data.frame(fac = factor(c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 6), rep("c", 4))),
+                  x1 = rnorm(15),
+                  x2 = rbinom(15, 10, .5))
> df
   fac          x1 x2
1    a -0.77738784  6
2    a  0.25487383  4
3    a  0.05457782  4
4    a  0.21403962  7
5    a  0.08518492  4
6    b -0.88929876  4
7    b -0.45661751  5
8    b  1.05712683  3
9    b -0.24521251  5
10   b -0.32859966  7
11   b -0.44601716  3
12   c -0.33795597  4
13   c -1.09185690  7
14   c -0.02502279  6
15   c -1.36800818  5
```

And the transformation:

```
> library(lfe)
> demeanlist(df[,c("x1", "x2")], list(df$fac))
            x1   x2
1  -0.74364551  1.0
2   0.28861615 -1.0
3   0.08832015 -1.0
4   0.24778195  2.0
5   0.11892725 -1.0
6  -0.67119563 -0.5
7  -0.23851438  0.5
8   1.27522996 -1.5
9  -0.02710938  0.5
10 -0.11049653  2.5
11 -0.22791403 -1.5
12  0.36775499 -1.5
13 -0.38614594  1.5
14  0.68068817  0.5
15 -0.66229722 -0.5
```

In other words, the following numbers are subtracted from groups `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
> library(doBy)
> summaryBy(x1+x2~fac, data = df)
  fac     x1.mean x2.mean
1   a -0.03374233     5.0
2   b -0.21810313     4.5
3   c -0.70571096     5.5
```

I'm sure I could figure out a function to do this, but I'll be calling it thousands of times on very large datasets, and would like to know if something fast and optimized has already been built, or is obvious to construct.